# How to use powershell to generate sequent numbers in same alignment?

Tags: powershell, numbers

I know use for loop or 1..1000 | %{ ... } to generate numbers in powershell like

```
1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, ...
```

Now I hope to generate sequent numbers like

```
0001, 0002, ... 0111, .... 0999, 1000
```

A workaround is to use chars and convert to int. Could you provide a simple way to do it?

Of course, solutions in other languages such as C#, Java are also welcomed for this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
1..1000 | foreach { $_.ToString('0000') }
```

Comment: Comparing with other answer, this looks more simple.

Answer (score 3):

How about applying formatting like this:

```
 1..10 | foreach {
    $i = "{0:0000}" -f $_
    $i
 }
```

Comment: remove the `$i` :  `1..10 | % { "{0:0000}" -f $_ }`

Answer (score 3):

this?

```
1..1000 | % { ([string]$_).padleft(4,'0') }
```