# Shorten PowerShell switch statement with multiple similar matches

Tags: powershell

I have a `switch` statement with multiple matches, with the matches being sequential:

```
switch ( ${env:COMPUTERNAME} ) {
    { ${env:COMPUTERNAME} -in "pc001", "pc002", "pc003", "pc004", "pc005", "pc006", "pc007", "pc008", "pc009", `
    "pc020", "pc021", "pc022", "pc023", "pc024", "pc025", "pc026", "pc027", "pc028", "pc029" } {
        Write-Output 'These PC are located at the 1st floor.';
        break;
    }
    { ${env:COMPUTERNAME} -in "pc010", "pc011", "pc012", "pc013", "pc014", "pc015", "pc016", "pc017", "pc018", "pc019" } {
        Write-Output 'These PC are located at the 2nd floor.';
        break;
    }
    default {
        Write-Output 'Unknown location.';
        break;
    }
}
```

I am new to PowerShell and am looking for a way to shorten the statement. If I were writing in Ash shell, I could have used `seq` to generate sequential numbers. I do not know how to achieve that in PowerShell. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use powershell to generate sequent numbers in same alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243711/how-to-use-powershell-to-generate-sequent-numbers-in-same-alignment)

Comment: What's the logic? Why are `pc02x` on the 1st floor and not the 3rd?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is a contrived example based on my real life problem: the values are not always sequential, but consist of multiple ranges instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -ge and -le:

```
switch ( 'pc011' ) {
  { $_ -ge 'pc001' -and $_ -le 'pc009' } { '1st floor' }
  { $_ -ge 'pc010' -and $_ -le 'pc019' } { '2nd floor' }
  { $_ -ge 'pc020' -and $_ -le 'pc029' } { '1st floor' }
  default { 'unknown' }
}

2nd floor
```

-And and -or have equal precedence in powershell, but this seems to work as well:

```
0..30 | % tostring pc000 | % { 
  switch ( $_ ) {
    { $_ -ge 'pc001' -and $_ -le 'pc009' -or 
      $_ -ge 'pc020' -and $_ -le 'pc029' } { "$_ 1st floor" }
    { $_ -ge 'pc010' -and $_ -le 'pc019' } { "$_ 2nd floor" }
    default { "$_ unknown" }
  }
}

pc000 unknown
pc001 1st floor
pc002 1st floor
pc003 1st floor
pc004 1st floor
pc005 1st floor
pc006 1st floor
pc007 1st floor
pc008 1st floor
pc009 1st floor
pc010 2nd floor
pc011 2nd floor
pc012 2nd floor
pc013 2nd floor
pc014 2nd floor
pc015 2nd floor
pc016 2nd floor
pc017 2nd floor
pc018 2nd floor
pc019 2nd floor
pc020 1st floor
pc021 1st floor
pc022 1st floor
pc023 1st floor
pc024 1st floor
pc025 1st floor
pc026 1st floor
pc027 1st floor
pc028 1st floor
pc029 1st floor
pc030 unknown
```

Or rename the computers to include the floor...

Comment: It works. But can we be safe and add brackets like this: `( $_ -ge 'pc001' -and $_ -le 'pc009' ) -or ( $_ -ge 'pc020' -and $_ -le 'pc029' ) }`? I do not know if brackets are valid syntax in PowerShell or not, at least in other programming languages they are used to change operator precedence.

Comment: You can........

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-Regex` mode switch to test the input against a regular expression instead:

```
switch -Regex (${ENV:COMPUTERNAME}) {
  '^pc0[02][0-9]$' {
    'These PC are located at the 1st floor.'
    break
  }
  '^pc01[0-9]$' {
    'These PC are located at the 2nd floor.'
    break
  }
  default {
    'Unknown location.'
  }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet works well, but I kind of prefer '-ge' and '-le' in @js2010 answer because it is easier for me to specify multiple ranges. Is there any neat way using Regex to specify that (pc010 - pc015) and (pc024 - pc027) are in the 1st floor? Notice that the right most numbers are now overlapped.